# C++ V8 object context

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm trying to perform a callback in C++ (where C++ is running as part of a node.js program). The callback is to a 3rd party library, where it will call the callback when it has data to pass.

The problem I appear to be having is with variable types:

```
static void sensorEventCallback(const char *protocol, const char *model,
        int id, int dataType, const char *value, int timestamp,
        int callbackId, void *context)
{
   //process the data here
}

Handle<Value> sensorEvents( const Arguments& args ) {
    HandleScope scope;
    ...
    callbackId = tdRegisterSensorEvent(
            reinterpret_cast<TDSensorEvent>(&telldus_v8::sensorEventCallback),
            Context::GetCurrent()->Global());
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> error: cannot convert ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’ to ‘void*’ for argument
>   ‘2’ to ‘int tdRegisterSensorEvent(void (*)(const char*, const char*,
>   int, int, const char*, int, int, void*), void*)’

It appears to be struggling with argument 2 which is the context. Any thoughts on how I can convert the V8 object to one that tdRegisterSensorEvent will accept?

Comment: It looks like you need to pass the address of the object and not the object itself.

Comment: @n.m. One shouldn't advocate [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) *(especially when v8.h is published source)*. `Context::GetCurrent()->Global()` returns a `Local<Context>`...

Comment: @HostileFork: I should have said "an object" and not "the object", for which I apologize. If a C function expects a `void*` you generally pass it some object's address. I didn't mean anything more than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snooping a bit, that `GetCurrent` appears to be defined in the V8 header to return a `Local<Context>`:

[v8.h on GitHub, location of GetCurrent() in the Context object definition](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/05e6f318c6ecccea73698367010e51812c5b3862/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L3400)

This `Local<T>` is a template for a *"lightweight, stack allocated handle"*, derived from a base class `Handle<T>`:

[v8.h on GitHub, definition of Local](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/05e6f318c6ecccea73698367010e51812c5b3862/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L257)

[v8.h on GitHub, definition of Handle](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/05e6f318c6ecccea73698367010e51812c5b3862/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L144)

So seems you've got a Context pointer whose lifetime is being managed by something called a `HandleScope`.  If you pull the context pointer out and save it to use in a callback later, it may or may not still exist at the time the call is made.

If you know all the callbacks will happen before it's freed by the handle scope, you can try getting the pointer out using the dereference operator overload and passing it:

[v8.h on GitHub, T* Handle::operator*()](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/05e6f318c6ecccea73698367010e51812c5b3862/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L213)

But you may not have this guarantee.

Comment: Fantastic info, thanks! You did a much better job of understanding the docs than I did! Indeed.. callbacks could happen hours after the event is registered - I'll have to find another way of getting node.js to talk to c++ and avoiding Handles..

Comment: None of this seemed to be in the docs, so I just went and read the header...!

Comment: @RichW thats why Persistant<T> is for

Answer (score 1):

As n.m. says I would guess the address of the context object should be passed. You can then cast that back in your callback

```
void telldus_v8::sensorEventCallback(const char *protocol, const char *model,
        int id, int dataType, const char *value, int timestamp,
        int callbackId, void *context)
{
   v8::Local<v8::Object>* ctx_ptr = static_cast<v8::Local<v8::Object>*>(context);
   //process the data here
}

v8::Local<v8::Object> ctx = Context::GetCurrent()->Global();
callbackId = tdRegisterSensorEvent(
        reinterpret_cast<TDSensorEvent>(&telldus_v8::sensorEventCallback),
        &ctx);
```

Comment: I thought the good part about the open source revolution was that we didn't have to *guess*!  :-/  *(It's a `Local<Context>`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13488780/211160))*